# My Debian laptop often does not resume from suspend. Where do I start?

Tags: debian, suspend, laptop

I am running Debian stable on a 4 year-old business laptop. The installation is completely standard (with no special drivers) and up to date. Unfortunately the laptop only resumes from suspend 8 times out of 10. The rest of the time, when waking up, the screen does not turn on and I have to perform a hard reset.

I would like to know **a good general procedure** to start debugging this problem. I know that step 1 is to carry out all software updates and step 2 is to identify any recognizable patterns (e.g. does it still happen when the wifi is turned off, etc.). I did this already and nothing comes to mind. My question is: what’s next? Which log files should I consult? In those, what should I look for? Which "bread crumbs" are left on the system after a crash to tell me what happened?

To be clear, I am not just trying to solve this specific problem (it’s a Dell Latitude 7280 on Debian 11, for what it’s worth), but to learn from solving the issue, too.

Comment: I would start by `/var/log/messages`, comparing what happens when it wake up and when it didn't. I you can afford another host running unix, maybe a distributed syslog.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great start. I am also looking at distributed logging, but it’s hard to see what problem this would solve. Are there other logs than /var/log/messages, too?